# SOQL query results differ on selecting from varying columns

Tags: soql, contact, bulk-api

I'm querying on Contact object where the results are varying on Bulk API vs querying on developer console.
Total records on Contact is 997820.

**Query on developer console:**

```
select count(id) from contact WHERE SystemModstamp <= 2018-11-09T04:41:54Z
```

yields 997820 records.

**Query on Bulk API:**

```
select id, name from contact WHERE SystemModstamp <= 2018-11-09T04:41:54Z
```

yields 997812 records.

**Query2 on Bulk API:**

```
SELECT Id, IsDeleted, MasterRecordId, AccountId, LastName, FirstName, Salutation, Name FROM Contact WHERE SystemModstamp <= 2018-11-09T04:41:54Z
```

yields 997820 records.

Why is there a disparity in the records that are retrieved through Bulk API?

P.S.:
I have also tried getting records through SOAP API with the same set of parameters: query operation (not queryAll). SOAP API retrieves 997812 records. The records that are missed are not deleted (isDeleted = false)

Comment: Are you using queryAll() for bulkAPI?

Comment: No. It is "query" for Bulk API.

Comment: is it an active sytem where records are still being inserted deleted?

Comment: You're definitely authenticated as the same user for the Bulk API as you're using in Developer Console, right?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Apparently, there were no specific changes that are being made to the object.

Comment: @DavidReed I'm accessing through the System Administrator profile and logged in with the same credentials through the developer console. Not sure what I'm missing though. I don't think the problem is with the developer console vs api access but the access through different queries, i.e. Query1 vs Query2.